# Is using React with JSX in web apps simmilar to using Java with XML in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, reactjs

I've recently become a front-end developer and with the release of Angular2 i've decided to find a new framework and have decided to try my hands at Reactjs and 
JSX. With my experience as a mobile developer i want to know if JSX works with Reactjs the way XML and Java work in android

Comment: no xml markup is more like angular than jsx. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `react-native` JSX's is used to define layouts and content presentation similar to XML in Android's development but it is more of an extension to ECMAScript than a separate markup language. From [the spec](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/):

> JSX is a XML-like syntax extension to ECMAScript without any defined
>   semantics. It's NOT intended to be implemented by engines or browsers.
>   It's NOT a proposal to incorporate JSX into the ECMAScript spec
>   itself. It's intended to be used by various preprocessors
>   (transpilers) to transform these tokens into standard ECMAScript.